# Can I run T-SQL update query from .sql file in Excel VBA and include variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I am new to SQL Express 2012.
I have an SQL statement running directly from Excel 2010 VBA which updates the database, similar to below.  I am using ADO and the command .Execute(stSQL) from within Excel.

```
stSQL = "UPDATE Organisation " _
   & "SET Org_Ref = '" & usrformtextbox1.Value & "', " _
        & "Org_Name = '" & usrformtextbox2.Value & "', " _
        & "Contact_Lastname = '" & usrformtextbox3.Value & "', " _
        & "Contact_Firstname = '" & usrformtextbox4.Value & "', " _
        & "Org_Contact_Email = '" & usrformtextbox5.Value & "', " _
        & "Org_Contact_Tel = '" & usrformtextbox6.Value & "', " _
    & "WHERE Org_ID = " & prikey
```

I want to take this 'hard coded' query out of Excel, save it, and execute it from an .sql file.
I have saved this into an .sql file.
I can read the .sql file into the variable stSQL, the textboxes are populated,but it will not now run with .Execute(stSQL).
I get an "Incorrect syntax near '&'" error.
Clearly I want the variables to be populated from my userfrom textboxes, automatically.
Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong and advise on my approach, syntax etc.  Thank you.

Comment: You have some quotes just before Org_Ref that need to be removed

Comment: You also have a comma at the end of the line before the "where" line that needs to be removed

Comment: @Graham, many thanks for responding. The comma I have spotted and removed thank you (to no avail I might add).  As for your code snippet I can't spot any difference so would you elaborate please.

Comment: @Graham, apols for the lack of attention to detail.  I have sorted out the stray commas etc. and pasted your code snippet.  Same error.  I tried using a different concatenation operator (+) and the same error message (but with ' near '+') and I have tried it just using one field - same error with the & operator.  Any other ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
stSQL = "UPDATE Organisation " _
   & "SET Org_Ref = '" & usrformtextbox1.Value & "', " _
        & "Org_Name = '" & usrformtextbox2.Value & "', " _
        & "Contact_Lastname = '" & usrformtextbox3.Value & "', " _
        & "Contact_Firstname = '" & usrformtextbox4.Value & "', " _
        & "Org_Contact_Email = '" & usrformtextbox5.Value & "', " _
        & "Org_Contact_Tel = '" & usrformtextbox6.Value & "' " _
    & "WHERE Org_ID = " & prikey
```

Comment: many thanks but can't get this to run when INPUT$ from an .sql file into stSQL.  Runs OK when it is hardcoded within VBA.  Any more takers for this one?